# How to plot 3D Earth in Python?

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot a satellite orbit around the Earth. This is what I currrently have:

[image]

I made this plot using the Axes3D function in mpl_toolkits.mplot3d. Ideally what I would like to do, is to replace the simple sphere with an actual Earth with topology.

If you're not sure what I mean, take a look at a MATLAB implementation:

http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13823-3d-earth-example

The Basemap package could be of help (especially the bluemarble() function), but unforunately I can't make it work on 3D objects. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365364/plotting-cylindrical-map-data-over-a-3d-sphere-in-python), but the answer to that question results in a projection of a 3D sphere on a 2D plot. I want a 3D sphere on a 3D plot, so that I'm able to rotate around it.

Does anybody know of another package/implementation. Or is there a way to make Basemap work with 3D objects?

---EDIT---

Somebody asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269099/creating-a-rotatable-3d-earth?lq=1), but nobody has answered it yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting cylindrical map data over a 3D sphere in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365364/plotting-cylindrical-map-data-over-a-3d-sphere-in-python)

Comment: not a duplicate... the answer to that question results in a projection of a 3D sphere on a 2D plot. I want a 3D sphere on a 3D plot, so that I'm able to rotate around it

Answer (score 2):

I have asked something similar some times ago

[PyOpenGL sphere with texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986754/pyopengl-sphere-with-texture)

If I were you I would pick a OpenGL and use a texture of Earth on it just like this one

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojwD8.jpg

In any case there is my second thread where I needed to make a Mars planet which is basically the same as you want except different texture:

[Why my texture is not showing PyOpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033625/why-my-texture-is-not-showing-pyopengl)