# How do you apply textures with pyopengl?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

How do I apply textures to a set of vertices? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I can't find any tutorials or anything on this subject, so I'm mostly going off of OpenGL docs and random scripts I find, so my code may not make any sense. My script is a bit too large to post here and most of it isn't relevant.

My set up for the texture:

```
def read_texture(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    img_data = numpy.array(list(img.getdata()), numpy.int8)
    textID = glGenTextures(1)
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
    return textID
```

Which I loaded with `texture_0 = read_texture('texture.png')`.

My setup for the cube:

generate cube's vertices

```
    def gen_rect_prism_vertices(xloc,yloc,zloc,x,y,z):
        x *= 0.5
        y *= 0.5
        z *= 0.5
        vertices = (
            (xloc+x, yloc-y, zloc-z),
            (xloc+x, yloc+y, zloc-z),
            (xloc-x, yloc+y, zloc-z),
            (xloc-x, yloc-y, zloc-z),
            (xloc+x, yloc-y, zloc+z),
            (xloc+x, yloc+y, zloc+z),
            (xloc-x, yloc-y, zloc+z),
            (xloc-x, yloc+y, zloc+z)
            )
        return vertices
```

defining the surfaces

```
rect_prism_surfaces = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (3,2,7,6),
    (6,7,5,4),
    (4,5,1,0),
    (1,5,7,2),
    (4,0,3,6)
    )
```

the main function

```
def block(xloc,yloc,zloc,x,y,z):
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture_0)
    vertices = gen_rect_prism_vertices(xloc,yloc,zloc,x,y,z)
    for surface in rect_prism_surfaces:
        n = 0
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        for vertex in surface:
            if n == 0:
                xv = 0.0
                yv = 0.0
            if n == 1:
                xv = 1.0
                yv = 0.0
            if n == 2:
                xv = 1.0
                yv = 1.0
            if n == 3:
                xv = 0.0
                yv = 1.0
            glTexCoord2f(xv,yv); glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
            n += 1
        glEnd()
```

This is the result.
[image: block]

Comment: Looks like you may not be binding the texture as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033625/why-my-texture-is-not-showing-pyopengl

Comment: @TEB I bind it in the beginning of the `block` function. So that's not it.

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you mean. It works now. Although part of the issue was the my version of PyOpenGL was a bit messed up, so I had to reinstall it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@TEB answered in a comment. The texture need to be bound(with `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture_0)`) in `read_texture()` where the texture ID is generated.