# Texture wrapping an entire sphere in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I copied the corrected code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033625/why-my-texture-is-not-showing-pyopengl) to apply my own texture from a solar imaging dataset onto an OpenGL sphere. In doing so I noticed that the texture does not wrap entirely around the sphere - only the "front half" - and the lighting shadow is not applied (also evident in the answer to that question).

How do you modify the code to wrap the texture around the *entire* sphere?

Here is the texture image which is data in a 360-degree longitude x sine(latitude) format (which actually should be transformed to longitude x latitude before applying to the sphere, but that's a detail...):

[image]

And here's the result of the texture mapping which shows that the image is only applied to the front/visible hemisphere:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want a transparent sphere? If not, what's the point of rendering the hidden half?

Comment: @Ripi2: no - see clarification in original question. I see your point about "rendering the hidden half", but the goal here is to eventually have a rotating sphere that shows the entire 360-degree dataset on the sphere. So it would seem the place to start is getting the texture on the entire 3D object and then proceeding with interactive rotation.

Comment: Applying a texture is wrapping the rectangle of the image to the desired form, a circle in your case. What did you expect?

Comment: Was expecting texture applied to a 3D sphere, not a circle.

Comment: If you want part of the texture, then you must calculate the part that is shown and pass its coordinates by using `glTexCoord`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap a texture around a sphere you have to distribute the texture coordinates quadratic around the sphere. This is provided by [`gluNewQuadric`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/gluNewQuadric.html), [`gluQuadricTexture`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/gluQuadricTexture.html) and [`gluSphere`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/gluSphere.html):

```
class MyWnd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.texture_id = 0
        self.angle = 0

    def run_scene(self):
        glutInit()
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
        glutInitWindowSize(400, 400)
        glutCreateWindow(b'Minimal sphere OpenGL')
        self.lightning()
        self.texture_id = self.read_texture('data/worldmap1.jpg')
        glutDisplayFunc(self.draw_sphere)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        gluPerspective(40, 1, 1, 40)
        glutMainLoop()

    def draw_sphere(self):
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluLookAt(math.cos(self.angle)*4, math.sin(self.angle)*4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        self.angle = self.angle+0.04
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture_id)
    
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        qobj = gluNewQuadric()
        gluQuadricTexture(qobj, GL_TRUE)
        gluSphere(qobj, 1, 50, 50)
        gluDeleteQuadric(qobj)

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    
        glutSwapBuffers()
        glutPostRedisplay()
```

See the preview:

[image]

See also [Immediate mode and legacy OpenGL](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/readme/content_python_legacy.md)

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for.