# Python Plotting map onto sphere

Tags: python, plot, 3d, visualization, cartopy

I have a map that I want to project onto a sphere, I use cartopy as suggested in another thread. I program in Jupyter.

My code is:

```
import os
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.chdir(os.getenv("HOME"))
os.chdir("Downloads/")
img = plt.imread("europamap1.jpg")

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(-10, 45))
ax.gridlines(color="black", linestyle="dotted")
ax.imshow(img, origin="upper", extent=(-180, 180, -90, 90),
          transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())  # Important

plt.show()
```

What I get is a white filled circle [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u2Fo.jpg)

I don't know why I cannot see any gridlines nor the image! I tried to plot.show(img) and the image is loaded! I basically just copied and pasted from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365364/plotting-cylindrical-map-data-over-a-3d-sphere-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The image file you are loading with `plt.imread`is not a geospatial raster format, which are commonly GeoTIFF files that end with the `.tiff` extension.

The problem is that your image lacks a coordinate reference system (CRS) to align with `cartopy`. For example `print(img.crs)` most likely does not print a CRS.

To project your data you will need to find a GeoTIFF file and align the CRS with the projection that `cartopy` uses - `ccrs.PlateCarree()`, for example.

Some test satellite imagery can be found here: https://gisgeography.com/usgs-earth-explorer-download-free-landsat-imagery/.

For reading and writing raster data, see `rasterio`: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Here is an example using a GeoTIFF from the source linked in the comments. https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/tiff/PIA03526.tif:.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio import plot

src = rasterio.open(r"../tests/data/PIA03526.tif")
plot.show(src)
```

Comment: oh wow, I did not realize that! would you know how to project such maps onto a globe? https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA03526

Comment: @RomeroAzzalini Yes, use the `rasterio` library! See my answer edits. Also, this notebook should get you started: https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/examples/Data%20visualization.ipynb.

Comment: it seems to work, but it's not what I want. I would to wrap the picture on a spherical surface (sphere radius=1) and would love to do some 3D trajetory plotting in the same picture aswell

Comment: @SamComber FYI, that notebook has been deleted from the rasterio sources. The maintainer said it was deprecated. Do you have another more current example somewhere?